# Formal way to say "hard to understand"

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

I want to say in a formal and more precise way (academic publication) that since something has been obfuscated, ***it is really hard to understand***.

By "hard to understand" I mean that understanding its internal structure would be complicated by an external person.

However, this formulation is too broad, too spontaneous for what I need to write.
What terms could I use to express this in a formal and concise manner?

Comment: Difficult to comprehend / decipher. Looking up synonyms, and checking example sentences in dictionaries / articles, is reasonable research; some signs of research are expected on ELU.

Comment: Indeed. The "formality" tag says " The question must identify a particular concern about the formality of the word or phrase at issue" which this question doesn't. Why is "hard to understand" not good enough? Is it actually the word *really* which is the problem?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I thought it was quite obvious why such a sentence can't appear in an academic publication, it's too broad and spontaneous. Yes *really* is part of the problem.

Comment: Like many questions here: incomprehensible.

Comment: [**abstruse**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/abstruse) adjective - ***difficult to understand**; obscure*.  Also, given it's a "50-cent word", this is one of those words that's "self-defining". (But I've forgotten what the word for *that* is! :)

Comment: @AntoineC. - I wasn't referring to your question -- it's actually reasonably clear.

Comment: Got it! They're [autological words](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/52927/17-words-describe-themselves) - for which the typically-cited example is ***sesquipedalian***.

Comment: @AntoineC. No, it's not obvious, which is why the tag says what it does. And if *really* is the problem, then that's what you should be asking about. What about just leaving that word out? What's actually wrong with "hard to understand", if something is hard to understand?

Comment: Isn’t saying that it has been obfuscated sufficient?  It feels like saying “since this has been painted there is now paint on it.”

Comment: @AntoineC, is the implication that the thing is *intentionally* obfuscated and hard to understand? That the author has gone out of his way to be obscure? In such cases "obfuscated" fully implies "intentionally made hard to understand for the outsider", although another good word in such cases may be that the thing is "cryptic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the word [intricate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intricate), meaning:

> with many complicated details that make something difficult to understand

or

> having a lot of small parts or pieces arranged in a complicated way, and therefore sometimes difficult to understand in detail

both of which may fit your description well.

Comment: Note that *intricate* only implies a high degree of essential detail or subtlety, perhaps to the degree of suggesting something is over-specialised or fragile - for example, a painting or a carving may be "intricate". It does not carry the implications of words like "obfuscated", which suggests that something is far more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

If it is hard to understand because it requires  intelligence that is  above average, then the word you are looking for is **abstruse**

> Relativity is an abstruse theory

[Here is the definition by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstruse)

However, if it is hard because of lack of prerequisite knowledge, then the the proper word is **recondite**

> Calculus is recondite for pupils who haven’t even studied Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

How about **obscure**?

According to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambiguous#synonyms), **obscure** implies a hiding or veiling of meaning through some inadequacy of expression or withholding of full knowledge.

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obscure), **obscure** means to make something difficult to discover and understand

Examples:

> The methodology used by X to derive Y from Z is **obscure**.
>
> X based her derivation of Y from Z on an **obscure** methodology.
>
> X's methodology **obscures** his derivation of Z from Y.

Comment: I think it is too much figurative, I would need a more neutral word.

Comment: @AntoineC. I don't know what you mean by *figurative* in this context. I also don't see how there could be a neutral word for something inherently negative: someone  making something "very difficult to understand" for the purpose of obfuscation. In contrast to *intricate*, for example, and to *incomprehensible*, *impenetrable*, etc., the Cambridge definition captures this intentionality. It's also not hard to imagine using it in an academic paper.

Answer (score 0):

You  have already used the word obfuscate. The corresponding adjective is [obfuscatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/obfuscatory)